# python kivy, i want to print button's text on button of scroll view

Tags: python, button, kivy, scrollview

for example :
if ı pressed button 1 this program will print(1)
if i pressed button 50 this program will print(50)

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App

class APP(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

APP().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the `on_release` attribute to the `Button` like this:

```
class APP(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40, on_release=self.butt)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

    def butt(self, button):
        print(button.text)
```